# Error: '...' does not exist in current working directory

Tags: r

Hi all :) Hope everyone is well during these trying times.

Sorry in advance for the extremely basic and nooby question. I have a worksheet to fill in and my lack of ability is already rearing it's head.

> ## to do: load in the data
>
> dat_d1 <- read_csv("Dawtry_Sutton_and_Sibley_2015_Study_1a")
> Error: 'Dawtry_Sutton_and_Sibley_2015_Study_1a' does not exist in current working directory ('/home/2607695h@campus.gla.ac.uk/Research Methods/R portfolio 2: correlation').

I have set my working directory to the correct folder so I'm struggling to see where I've gone wrong.

Any help would be really, really appreciated. Thanks all, speak soon.

Comment: You may need `.csv` at the end i.e. `"Dawtry_Sutton_and_Sibley_2015_Study_1a.csv")`

Comment: You forgot to specify the file type as e.g. csv: `dat_d1 <- read_csv("Dawtry_Sutton_and_Sibley_2015_Study_1a.csv")`

Comment: Thank you everyone, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

base R:

```
dat_d1 <- read.csv("Dawtry_Sutton_and_Sibley_2015_Study_1a.csv")
```

if you want to use read_csv  ->
install.packages("tidyverse")
and load
library(tidyverse)

tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse) # after installing over install.packages("tidyverse")

dat_d1 <- read.csv("Dawtry_Sutton_and_Sibley_2015_Study_1a.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `fread` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dat_d1 <- fread("Dawtry_Sutton_and_Sibley_2015_Study_1a.csv")
```

Comment: Thanks akrun, I really appreciate the help!